# Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" after loading required dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty, slf4j

I am building my maven project and deploying in jetty server and I get this issue. In my ${jetty_home}/lib, I am having jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar, jul-to-slf4j-1.7.2.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar. Along with my maven project, I am having

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

In the mvn dependency tree, for slf4j, I see the following:

```
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:provided (scope not updated to compile)
```

Apart from this, I have commons-logging-1.2.jar bundled with my project. Now I build my maven project and if I run that using my eclipse jetty plugin, I am having no issues and perfectly everything is working fine. 
After that, I try to deploy this in remote server on a jetty webapp folder, and now I get,

```
Establishing start.log on Wed Jul 08 12:46:13 PDT 2015
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I followed the steps mentioned in other posts regarding this, but still unable to fix this. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put SLF API in a wrong class loader.

Class loader hierarchy looks something like this (it may be a bit inaccurate):

```
BootstrapClassLoader - loads Java classes
   ^
   |
ExtClassLoader - loads some additional libs
   ^
   |
AppClassLoader - loads Jetty and slf4j-api
   ^
   |
WebAppClassLoader - loads your application and can load slf4j-impl
```

Your classes trigger loading slf4j-api packages and that causes delegation from `WebAppClassLoader` to `AppClassLoader`. Then slf4j-api classes will try to load slf4j-impl classes, but will only ask `AppClassLoader` for them. This class loader cannot delegate to your application class loader (that is delegate down in the diagram). It only delegates up and finds nothing, hence the error.

You have to put these libraries in the same class loader. Either in the jetty/lib or WAR.

Comment: Thanks Michal for responding back. I tried to add all the 4 jars, slf4j-api, slf4j-log4j12, jcl-over-slf4j, jul-to-slff4j in my application war and deployed it into jetty. Still facing the same problem. Not sure what I am missing in this config

Comment: Did you remove these jars from Jetty's lib folder? If slf4j-api is still there you will keep getting the error. What version of Jetty do you use?

Comment: Actually I tried it the other way now, by removing the jars from my application war and retaining it only in jetty and it worked :-) Thanks a lot for your comments and explanation.